# Overwrite A device administrator App xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, device, administrator

Good morning,
I Need some help to solve an issue that I found on my android application.
I have created an android application that has device administrator permission using a PC ***A***
now I have moved to a different PC, ***B*** and when I open the same project on my visual studio and generate the apk from the new PC, if I try to reinstall it by opening the apk on the android device where there is already install the application it fails.(application not installed)

If I open the same project on my old pc, I can generate the apk and reinstall on it (application installed).

I have checked and all option on android are the same.same sdk version same min sdk etc.
Do you know if the are some "key" to copy from my old pc?
the only solution that I have is format the android device and reinstall the application because when the android application is device administrator I can't uninstall it.

thanks and regards,
andrea

Comment: Use the same keystore to sign your apk no matter what build PC is used to create the apk (that keystore used to sign release versions of the apk should be backed up and stored securely)

Comment: Hi,i found the keystore under debug folder.so i solved the issue.thanks regards andrea